# How to make a Youtube video continue when page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, youtube

I was wondering if it's possible to save the current **Youtube** video position and when the page refresh, the video would start at this last position and not restart from the start.

Using cookie to save the last position or with GET. In fact my web
site won't refresh often since my page are call in background with
Ajax and replaced into a div, but if the user refresh the page, the
music will start from the start but I'd rather make it continues where it where before the refresh.

---

### **Here what I did:**

PHP will print the cookie into the url like this after the param *start=*

```
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIR3KAfhqZQ?version=3&autoplay=1&start=<?php print($_COOKIE['YTTIME']); ?>
```

Then in javascript I set a Timeout that continuously save an integrer(seconds) cookie.

```
var YTT   = parseInt(getCookie("YTTIME")); // Current Video Time
var YTTL  = 802;                 // Total video length in seconds

function SaveYTTIMEtoCookie() {
    setTimeout(function(){

        if (YTT < YTVL) YTT++;   // If current time is smaller than the maximum length
        else YTT = 0;            // Or restart to 0

        setCookie("YTTIME", YTT, 1); // SetCookie is a custom function
        SaveYTTIMEtoCookie();        // Loop the SetTimeout every 1 second.
    },1000);
}
```

How to save cookie in JS: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)
How to setTimeout in JS: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

> But having 2 or more windows opened at the same time will mess this up
>   by adding +1 to the cookie in every page... :/ any solution?

Comment: You can use  a dinamic load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the time in seconds into the URL to start at a certain time

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SbUC-UaAxE#t=170

t is time in seconds from the start.

If you are using the API,  then you can track the current distance they are in the video and then reload it always with this value.

But you will have to constantly write to a cookie or localstorage in JS and then reread that value in seconds.

Comment: Thanks that's totally the answer :)